# Movie featuring  space crew, murders, a forbidden door and ending with a revelation

Tags: movie, story-identification

I searched wide and far and couldn't come up with a title for a movie I watched somewhere around the mid-90ies up to early 00's as a rerun in late-night television (in Germany, specifically on Vox; but I'm sure it was an American movie to begin with).

Basically, what I remember from the story revolves around a crew in a space station or maybe space ship of some sort. Some crew members murder other crew members and there is some kind of door they are not supposed/unable to go through.
Late in the movie they do go through the door and I'm pretty sure one of the first views is a skeleton of a dead security guard. It turns out the whole thing was some kind of simulation gone wrong and they find themselves to be in a (nuclear?) wasteland. And that's pretty much the revelation/wrap-up of the movie, as I recall it.

I would be delighted if somebody had any idea what movie this could be :) Thanks!

EDIT: The whole movie was in color and I think it was feature-length, not just 45 mins.

Comment: That sounds like it could be a Twilight Zone episode.

Comment: I think there's an _Outer Limits_ episode (from the original series) that resembles that.  Was it in black and white and could it be just a TV episode?

Comment: This rings a huge bell... I may have seen this, I'll see if I can remember anything.

Comment: I think I'm looking for this movie too. I only remember it extremely vaguely. I think my parents rented it when I was a kid. I know it wasn't a twilight zone or outer limits. I don't remember the part about the door. But for some reason I think there was a little person it. And I have this weird visual of the murderer injecting poison into some medical blood pumping type apparatus. It's all a very distant memory so I could be wrong.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe the film has two names, either [*Star Quest* or *Terminal Voyage*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_Voyage).

If it is the same one I'm thinking of, the crew wake up from cryo sleep with the captain dead. The new captain gets to watch some video (I think) which sent them crazy for some reason. I believe this happens a few time with the new captain going crazy each time before they somehow break out and find its all a simulation. There's also some virtual reality bits I believe?

Comment: Whoa, I could kiss you right now! I've spent countless hours since my original post going through movie descriptions to find this! Very much appreciated! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Vaguely the plot line of PKD's "A Maze of Death"

Answer (score 2):

Sounds somewhat like the episode of Outer Limits entitled "[Dead Man's Switch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_Man%27s_Switch_%28The_Outer_Limits%29)."

Comment: Hmm, I'm pretty sure they were all in the same simulation and the ending is them getting out of it. Also, I think it was a feature film and not a single episode of Outer Limits or Twilight :/

Comment: Doesn't really sound the same.