# Old sci-fi movie set in ship with murderous crew

Tags: story-identification, movie

This one I saw when I was very young on Cinemax (when they would show B-flicks like nobody else's business), so I will write the stuff I remember:

- Story happened on a ship (colony or something), enroute to another planet.
- Captain died in cryo-sleep at the beginning, crew gets message that they are all that remains of mankind. Or Earth was already destroyed and they were coming out of cryo-don't recall.
- Crew turns on each other, start killing each other. One of crew members (a woman) is android, is last to be killed.
- Two crew members remaining (man and woman) try to arm escape pod to run away from ship self-destruct that android triggered, but are unable to.
- They open eyes after bracing to be blown up to discover that they are in a simulation in a bunker. They get message from unknown man in hologram that tells them about status of simulation (namely, that they "won"). Man ends his message by saying that "Darwin was right" or something.
- Both crew members leave bunker to find out that they are still on Earth… which has been destroyed.

Need help with, at the very least, the title.

I'll appreciate any help.

Comment: Are you certain it's a film (e.g. as opposed to an episode of something like Outer Limits)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is a duplicate of [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/12704/movie-featuring-space-crew-murders-a-forbidden-door-and-ending-with-a-revelat), if so the answer should be the same, a movie called "Terminal Voyage"--the plot summary [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_Voyage) certainly sounds very close to what you describe, with everyone waking up from hibernation to find the captain dead, killing and suspicion breaking out among the crew, and an end reveal that it had been a simulation but that they were on an Earth that had been ruined by nuclear war.